# How can i check in front-end if user input is valid based on my ANTLR grammar in back-end?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, antlr4

I've written some logic using the ANTLR parser, in Java, in the back-end of our software (frontend in Angular 2+). I've linked some front-end inputs to this back-end logic which works fine, but it would very easy for a user to make some typo and get some server internal errors.

I'm looking for a way to check if the user's input is valid before he sends his request to the server, and potentially make suggestions based on my grammar file. I've seen many examples using ANTLR with JS / TS. But I really don't want to rewrite everything from Java -> JS and, even more important, might not want all the logic to be available in front end.

Any ideas how i could generate some useful files based on my grammar file that would, at least, just check validity ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With your grammar you generated a parser, right? And with that parser you can parse the user input, which is the validation you are looking for. What else do you want?

Comment: The big thing is that my parser is in  the code back-end. I'd like to check input validity before user submits his query. But @Jason White solution sounds promising

Answer (score 1):

You could create an endpoint on your backend that validates an input then create a custom async validator in Angular to call that endpoint.

Rough idea might be...

#### form.component.ts

```
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
  input: ['', [Validators.required, AntlrValidator.checkGrammarValidity]]
});
```

#### antlr.validator.ts

```
export class AntlrValidator{
  static checkGrammarValidity(control: AbstractControl) => {
    const input = control.value; 
    // Your async http request to server to validate input.
    this.antlrService.checkGrammarValidity(input).map(res => {
      return res ? null : { validGrammar: true };
    })
  }
}
```

> https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that could work out ! I'll try this solution and update my post as progress is being made